# RewriteRule in htaccess only work when I visit url directly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have htaccess file where I am turning regurlar url 
`example.com/result?from=Brampton&to=Calgary&submit=` to 
`Rides-From-Toronto-Calgary-submit` seo friendly url. But problem is that I manually have to type url to visit seo friendly version of url, how can I achieve redirect using `.htaccess` ?

This is what I have so far

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^from [NC]
RewriteRule ^Rides-From-([^/]*)-([^/]*)-([^/]*)$ result?from=$1&to=$2&submit=$3 [QSA,NC,L,R=301]
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Seeing your profile came to know you never accepted any answer of questions Give it sometime when few answers are there, check them and reply back to users how it went. For gratitude you could up-vote all helpful answers(to encourage users on SO) and could accept an answer out of them all. you could see this link [What one could do when someone gets helpful answer on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) cheers and happy learning. Now also you could go to your OLD answers and could accept an answer wherever its applicable, cheers.

Comment: Have you changed your site to link to the "Rides-From-" version of the links?

Comment: Html form get method does not send SEO friendly request it send it with ?something=123 @Stephen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following .htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Also these Rules consider that your internal rewrite is happening to index.php file in case its something else file then please change its name to it in rules.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##External redirect rules.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/result\.php\?from=([^&]*)&to=([^&]*)&submit=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^  /Rides-From-%1-%2-%3=%3? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite rules from here...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:.*?-){2}([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)=(.+)/?$ result.php?from=$1&to=$2&$3=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I did that as well. No luck.

Comment: @Harry, please do mention which sample link you are using? And what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any errors. it's just I manually have to type url example.com/Rides-From-Toronto-whatever I want apache to automatically redirect to SEO-friendly version.

Comment: I modified your htaccess code (sorry I also have submit var that is required) and code works
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/result\?from=([^&]*)&to=([^&]*)&(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /Rides-From-%1-%2-%3? [R=301,L]
##Internal rewrite rules from here
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRUle ^Rides-From-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)/?$ result.php?from=$1&to=$2&submit=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
is there is any way I can replace space in paramters with something like _ symbol. current output Rides-From-Parm1%2b%2bON-Param2%2b%2bON-submit=

Comment: just want to remove %2b%2b which is showing in url (if there is space in parameter provided eg city state and rewrite rule is writing city%2b%2bstate

Comment: @Harry, I have edited rules now please do check it once 

Comment: I really appreciate your help bro <br> with this RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/result\?from=([^&]*)&to=([^&]*)&(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /Rides-From-%1-%2-%3? [R=301,L,NE]
##Internal rewrite rules from here...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRUle ^Rides-From-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)/?$ result.php?from=$1&to=$2&submit=$3 [QSA,L,NC] my url looks like this /Rides-From-Brampton++ON-Montreal+QC-submit=
is there any way we can replace that ++ sign with _ ? I am sorry if asking too much moreover that submit should not show = in end

Comment: @Harry, could you please confirm if you are hitting link `example.com/result?from=Brampton&to=Calgary&submit=`??

Comment: I am hitting link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247740/discussion-between-harry-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: @Harry, Sorry can't join chat, please do comment here, your previous comment is not completed, what is the sample link you are hitting if you can mention I can check on my code then, cheers.

Comment: @Harry, Hey buddy, going and checking code/urls details on other site is NOT at all encouraged. So please do mention 2 simple things which I am keep asking you, which url you are hitting and which url you want it to become?

Comment: Sorry for confusion how this simply. Url I am hitting `result.php?from=LocationA&to=LocationB&submit=submit` and url I want `Rides-From-LocationA-LocationB-submit=submit` and What we have so far achieved is `Rides-From-LocationA++state-LocationB++state-submit=Submit`

Comment: @Harry, No problem, So basically you are hitting: `result.php?from=LocationA&to=LocationB&submit=submit` just asking to make sure `**` are only your showing purposes representation correct?

Comment: ** was just representation yes.

Comment: @Harry, ok Sir jee, I have updated my code, please do check it and update your htaccess with new rules. Make sure 2 things, 1st: your .htaccess file is sitting along with result.php AND 2nd: clear your browser cache before testing URLs.

Comment: only thing left is (if possible) replace **'++'** with **'_'** sign which is appearing in url because when I provide params from html form, I have space in names Eg: **Yubacity CA** and its showing **Yubacity++CA**

Comment: @Harry, Please do check my updated rules, and follow my previous comment's instructions and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I dont know if we are on same page but my url result looks like this `https://example.com/result?from=Brampton++ON&to=Toronto++ON&submit=Submit` with **RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/result\?from=([^&]*)&to=([^&]*)&submit=([^&]*)&(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /Rides-From-%1-%2-%3? [R=301,L,NE]

##Internal rewrite rules from here...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRUle ^Rides-From-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)/?$ result.php?from=$1&to=$2&submit=$3 [QSA,L,NC]** .htaccess file just dont want **++** symbols as url space holders

Comment: @Harry, rules and its regex is fine only, change line FROM `RewriteRule ^  /Rides-From-%1-%2-%3=%3? [R=301,L]` TO `RewriteRule ^  /Rides-From-%1-%2-%3=%3? [R=301,L,NE]` once and let me know how it goes.

Comment: its already same **RewriteRule ^ /Rides-From-%1-%2-%3? [R=301,L,NE]**

Comment: @Harry, Ok try changing line FROM `RewriteRule ^  /Rides-From-%1-%2-%3=%3? [R=301,L]` TO `RewriteRule ^  /Rides-From-%1-%2-%3=%3? [R=301,L,B]` using `B` flag here. let me know how it goes.

Comment: **%2B%2B** shows when we use **B** flag

Comment: @Harry, Ok try changing it to `RewriteRule ^  /Rides-From-%1-%2-%3=%3? [R=301,L,B,NE]`?

Comment: `/Rides-From-Brampton%2B%2BON-Toronto%2B%2BON-submit%3DSubmit` alot of `%2B` instead of `++` now

Comment: @Harry, Ok then B flag is not working for you. So do you have other rules apart from these shown ones in your question? usually these flags work not sure why they are not working as of now for you.

Comment: are meant to repalce `++` placeholder in url? anyway you helped me alot. Thanks alot my friend.. Now I understand I had to write internal and external rewrite rules. Although it will take some time for me to understand how it works

Comment: @Harry, no usually these characters come from redirection only OR if there are multiple redirections happening. That's why I asked if there are other rules apart from these ones?

Comment: `Options -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
## ID new ride.php result.php?id= to ride-$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ride-([^/]*)$ result.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: #wroking okay
#External redirect rules.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/result\?from=([^&]*)&to=([^&]*)&(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /Rides-From-%1-%2-%3? [R=301,L,NE]

##Internal rewrite rules from here...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRUle ^Rides-From-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)/?$ result.php?from=$1&to=$2&submit=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
#remove .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]'